# Как использовать данные из QueryDict безопасно?

Tags: python, json, django

Я получаю данные через `ajax` в `python` словарём:

```
data = {
        a1: ['YESSSSSSSS',print('ry'),'LOLO'],
    }
```

Соответственно на сервере распаковываю так:

```
dict( request.GET.lists() )
```

`data['a1'][1]` выполняет код (если запустить, подставив вместо `request.GET` - `{'a1[]': ['YESSSSSSSS', 'LOLO'], '_': ['1610980865348']}`, то откроется окно).

В общем, здесь получается дыра для безопасности, а мне нужно принимать только строки!

Посоветуйте пж.

Comment: `json.loads` ? ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, спасибо. А не могли бы вы привести простенький пример пожалуйста (❁´◡`❁)

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, что это — то, что надо, но можно использовать модуль json из стандартной библиотеки. Как-то так:

```
import json
res = json.loads('{"key": "val", "list": [1, 2, 3]}')
```

Тогда в `res` будет:

> ```
> {'key': 'val', 'list': [1, 2, 3]}
> ```

Comment: Не совсем то. Попробуйте запустить так: ```import json
res = json.loads('{"key": print("ry"), "list": [1, 2, 3]}')```. В таком случае ```print("ry")``` обработается не как строка. А нужно, чтобы все содержимое не содержало кода, который мог бы выполняться.

Comment: @Леонид Ну так оно ж не выполнится.

Comment: как же, выполниться. Я проверил, у меня выполняется.